# Performing a clean install of the Upgrade version of Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If I’m performing a an upgrade to Windows 8, do I have to have the previous version installed, or is just having the key enough?](https://superuser.com/questions/493586/if-im-performing-a-an-upgrade-to-windows-8-do-i-have-to-have-the-previous-vers)

Is it ossible to clean install the **Upgrade** version of Windows 8?

I'm assuming to do this I'll need my Windows 7 Key and Windows 8 Key whilst doing the clean install. ANy other steps involved in this process?

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone confirm if it be possible to clean install the Upgrade
>   version of Windows 8?

The answer is of course you will. You only need to have an Windows 7 installed on the same storage device to use the Windows 8 upgrade license.

Comment: I assume then, the fact that Windows 7 will be compeltely wiped off the disk if its a clean install, then the Upgrade purely checks you have Windows 7 before continuing with the Windows 8 clean Installation?

Comment: Generally, even with a clean install, unless you reformat the partition, your old version of windows will get stuck into a folder called windows.old, or something like that.

Comment: @BBlake clean install has 2 meanings now, clean but keeps old install as you stated, then there is delete the partition for a absolute clean install.

Comment: Yea.  For example, I upgraded a laptop from XP to Win8 RTM.  Because it was a change from 32 bit to 64 bit, I couldn't do an upgrade install.  It moved the XP into a folder and installed Win8 "fresh".

Comment: So I guess my question is, is it possible to do a reformat clean install with Windows 8 upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it may be possible (I haven't tried this, so I can't verify 100%) - here is a [tutorial](http://www.mydigitallife.info/clean-install-windows-7-with-upgrade-media-and-product-key-on-formatted-or-empty-blank-hard-drive/) for installing Windows 7 from an upgrade CD - I hope this helps you as well.