# Installed Windows 8 Upgrade AFTER Formatting HD - any way to activate?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If I’m performing a an upgrade to Windows 8, do I have to have the previous version installed, or is just having the key enough?](https://superuser.com/questions/493586/if-im-performing-a-an-upgrade-to-windows-8-do-i-have-to-have-the-previous-vers)

I had an XP system - formatted the HD then ran Windows 8 Upgrade install.  Install was fine.

It cannot activate and gives me the 'this is an upgrade' error.  Is there ANY way to fix this (MS Support call or something?) before I scrap the entire Windows 8 install, Reinstall XP, then upgrade to Windows 8 the proper way?

I hate to waste the day's worth of config-the-new-os time if not absolutely necessary.

Error was the `0XC004F061` from Windows 8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If I'm performing a an upgrade to Windows 8, do I have to have the previous version installed, or is just having the key enough?](http://superuser.com/questions/493586/if-im-performing-a-an-upgrade-to-windows-8-do-i-have-to-have-the-previous-vers) also see: [Install Windows 8 Upgrade to a new SSD?](http://superuser.com/questions/493747/install-windows-8-upgrade-to-a-new-ssd)

Comment: Why not just call MS Support like you suggested?  They'll give you the scoop on what you need to do. :)

Comment: Unless you have a System Builder license you won't be able to upgrade.  You should have just selected "Clean Install" from within Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did a clean install of Windows 8, you should be able to work around the product activation issue as follows:

1. Open **Registry Editor** (`regedit`).
2. Navigate to the registry key:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\OOBE
   ```
3. Modify the value **MediaBootInstall** changing it from 1 to **0**.
4. Open a **Command Prompt** as Administrator.
5. In the Administrator Command Prompt window, run:

   ```
   slmgr -rearm
   ```
6. Restart the computer.
7. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, type **Activate Windows** into the Search box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
8. Now enter your product key.

If you have Windows activated at this point, then stop and enjoy.

If at this point it still refuses to accept the product key, then continue on with:

1. Open a **Command Prompt** as Administrator.
2. In the Administrator Command Prompt window, run:

   ```
   slmgr -ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
   ```

   inserting your Product Key instead of `XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX`.
3. In the Administrator Command Prompt window, run:

   ```
   slmgr -ato
   ```

Check that Windows is activated now.

If it's STILL not activated (very unlikely), then use the nuclear option:

1. Install a previous version of Windows onto the blank hard drive.
2. Install Windows 8 over this version of Windows. Choose to keep Nothing, and delete the `windows.old` folder after installation.

Comment: Thanks - I actually ended up backing out and reinstalling Windows 7 for now.  Going to use Windows 8 as a virtual machine until I am a little more familiar with the OS and interface.  Appreciate the help!