# How do I transfer Windows 8 upgrade license to new PC?

Tags: windows-8, license, windows-activation, windows-8-upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 Pro Upgrade but no previous version of Windows installed](https://superuser.com/questions/493631/windows-8-pro-upgrade-but-no-previous-version-of-windows-installed)

I recently bought the Windows 8 Pro upgrade pack and updated my current PC from Windows 7. I have the Windows 7 Family Upgrade Pack which allows installation on three PCs (all of which were installed).

I am looking at building a new PC in the coming months and want to transfer the Windows 8 install on the existing PC as a new, clean install on the new PC.

I'm fairly sure that the edition that I bought allows transfer between PCs. However, I have also heard that attempting to install from the upgrade media on a clean PC fails to activate.

How would I go about transferring the license to the new PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the "double-install" trick works to do this.

Duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/493631/windows-8-pro-upgrade-but-no-previous-version-of-windows-installed).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the Windows 8 upgrade can only be used on machines that already have Windows 7 pre installed.

Comment: According to the Microsoft website: To install the Windows 8 Pro upgrade, your PC must be running Windows XP SP3, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 Consumer Preview, or Windows 8 Release Preview.