# Windows 8 upgrade offer: will I be able to format or forced to upgrade?

Tags: windows-8, windows-installation, windows-8-upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If I’m performing a an upgrade to Windows 8, do I have to have the previous version installed, or is just having the key enough?](https://superuser.com/questions/493586/if-im-performing-a-an-upgrade-to-windows-8-do-i-have-to-have-the-previous-vers)
>   [Windows 8 Pro Upgrade but no previous version of Windows installed](https://superuser.com/questions/493631/windows-8-pro-upgrade-but-no-previous-version-of-windows-installed)

I'm considering buying Windows 8 Pro with Upgrade offer. I'm currently using Windows 7.

My question is very simple: Will the installation DVD to be downloaded be able to install Windows 8 from *scratch* or does it need Windows 7 to be installed?

I'm asking this because I will **eventually** format my computer and I prefer installing an OS from scratch rather from an existing installation.

Comment: Its entirely up to you. What upgrade options you have is WELL DOCUMENTED so I won't repeat them.  You will be unable to use the upgrade license unless there is an existing installation present.  You can choose to do a clean install that will end in the same result as formatting the hdd.

Comment: @Ramhound would you care to clarify? I was under the impression that the only requirement was that you have a Windows 7 license already. While the clean install has worked for me (and validated via Microsoft Tech Support), making it a semi-moot point, I'd like to make sure I'm within the license agreement.

Comment: @AK4749 - A "Clean Install" will migrate nothing.  While it does not format the hdd, nothing is carried into the Windows 8 installation, thus making it practically the same.  If you really want to install Windows 8 not within Windows that requires a System Builder personal use (OEM) license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use the [Clean Install trick from Windows 7](http://winsupersite.com/article/windows-7/clean-install-windows-7-with-upgrade-media-128512) in Windows 8:

- Install Windows 8 with your key
- Open regedit.exe with Start Menu Search and navigate to:

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Setup/OOBE/
- change the value MediaBootInstall from "1" to "0"
- run slgmr.vbs -rearm and reboot
- activate Windows 8.

Comment: awesome, will keep this in mind haha

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if a Windows 8 Pro Upgrade disc can be used to perform a clean install, it is indeed possible and I have done so successfully. You will, however, be required to call in to tech support each time you do so so that they can verify your installation is legitimate.

EDIT: The line you call is not restricted to regular business hours, and is quite convenient, from my experience. It took about 5 minutes last time I called, with about 2 minutes actually speaking to the tech. (11pm EST)

Comment: I upgraded fine without calling in. I ran the upgrade advisor. Paid my $40 ($15 for me since I had a new laptop) and it downloaded the OS for me and gave me a product key. Then I just made a bootable USB (from the options given at the end) and booted into Windows 8 and did a clean install. it was nice.

Comment: @masfenix ah, did you have Windows 7 installed when you performed the clean install? I had already wiped my drive at that point through a Ubuntu LiveCD. Good to know that that is an option though, thanks!

Comment: Availability hours usually change with country :)

Comment: Yes I had windows 7, but i don't think the installation checks for existing operating systems. I think you may need to have a xp/vista/7 machine to get the $40 offer, but thats about that.