# How to install Windows 8 OS on Windows 7 Ultimate system

Tags: windows-8, installation

Please let me know how to delete my current OS (Window 7 Ultimate is currently on my system).

After deleting it, how do I download Windows 8 and make a bootable DVD/CD and install it?

Comment: If you have windows 8, you can get the media or ISO. Burn to DVD or prepare an install USB key with the USB download system. Install formatting the old install. What's the issue there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 Pro Upgrade but no previous version of Windows installed](http://superuser.com/questions/493631/windows-8-pro-upgrade-but-no-previous-version-of-windows-installed)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a clean windows 8 install

Just follow these steps

1. Completely backup your current system and data (in case something goes wrong during the installation)
2. Purchase Windows 8 (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/buy)
   if you have the .iso file, burn it to a dvd (I recommend CDBurner XP)
3. Boot into the windows 8 installation DVD
4. Follow the steps (if you are asked which type of installation you want, choose custom)
5. Now, you have to choose on what partition you want to install windows, to delete the previous version of windows completely, click drive options and delete all partitions, now make new partitions (I recommend 2 partitions, 50% of your drive system, the other half, data.
   select your partition on which you want to install Windows and click next
6. Let the setup do it's work and choose your custom settings

I hope this helped!