# Use Windows 8 upgarde key for a clean install later

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If I’m performing a an upgrade to Windows 8, do I have to have the previous version installed, or is just having the key enough?](https://superuser.com/questions/493586/if-im-performing-a-an-upgrade-to-windows-8-do-i-have-to-have-the-previous-vers)

I'm planning to upgrade to Windows 8 Pro.

I want to know whether or not will I be able to use the Product key I get from upgrade of $39.99 for a clean install later without any hassles?

In other words, is the upgrade key complete in itself for clean installs later or are there any conditions attached?

Answer (score 2):

> Does the upgrade need to be done on a PC with Windows already
>   installed? The license terms for the upgrade require upgrading from a
>   valid “genuine” version of Windows. Visit
>   http://www.microsoft.com/genuine/ if you are not certain whether or
>   not your PC has genuine Windows.
>   http://www.windowsupgradeoffer.com/en-US/Home/Faq

I did this with the Windows 7 upgrade. I could not do it on a blank drive, it had to have Vista on it. However, after Vista was on it (didn't even have to boot up), I was able to select the custom install, delete and format the partitions and install Windows 7 cleanly. Whether this changed for 8 I don't know, but according to the FAQ you have a to have a qualifying base OS.