# "windows 8 pro upgrade" should I own a previous version of windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If I’m performing a an upgrade to Windows 8, do I have to have the previous version installed, or is just having the key enough?](https://superuser.com/questions/493586/if-im-performing-a-an-upgrade-to-windows-8-do-i-have-to-have-the-previous-vers)

As I see from here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/terms-conditions

There is no requirement for buying a previous version of windows, it only says that you should have running one of those. I mean, you can use evaluation version or unactivated version which are legally accessible. And do this windows 8 pro upgrade. Also here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/buy it says: "To install Windows 8 Pro, customers must be running Windows XP SP3, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 Consumer Preview, or Windows 8 Release Preview." If I'm not mistaking Windows 8 Consumer Preview and Windows 8 Release Preview are freely available.

So what I'm asking is, is it said anywhere that I must own previous version of windows to windows 8 pro upgrade?

Please don't confuse this upgrade with another available only for a PC bought with preinstalled windows 7.

Comment: Actually your previous license must be valid in order to use the Windows 8 Upgrade license. The installer is going to verify your windows license is legit.  If you want a clean installion use the System Builder license stop trying to cheat microsoft out of money.

Comment: It doesn't verify anything actually. It doesn't ask your previous license.

Comment: Doesn't matter you still need a eligible license on the machine to use the upgrade license otherwise you don't have a legal installation of Windows 8 or Windows 8 Professional.

Answer (score 0):

It stands to reason that the Windows you have running now has to be some aquired by legal means (it came with the machine, was a legal upgrade, or was purchased separately).

Comment: You can download some windows versions absolutely legally and install them. You won't be able to activate them and they will work for a limited period of time.

Comment: @dhblah - Except Windows 8 and Windows 8 Professional does not have a trial period.  So you cannot legally download and install it without having a license for it.  Only Windows 8 Enterprise has a 90 day trial, which CANNOT be upgraded to a full license, it must be reinstalled in order to do so.