# Is it possible to upgrade from a clean install in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Performing a clean install of the Upgrade version of Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/469907/performing-a-clean-install-of-the-upgrade-version-of-windows-8)
>   [If I’m performing a an upgrade to Windows 8, do I have to have the previous version installed, or is just having the key enough?](https://superuser.com/questions/493586/if-im-performing-a-an-upgrade-to-windows-8-do-i-have-to-have-the-previous-vers)

Does Windows 8 support upgrading from a clean install. For example, buying the upgrade key and entering it on a clear install?

Or is it functionally necissary to have the version you are upgrading from installed on the computer.

The former was the case with Windows 7, but I recal Windows 2000 needed the an installed copy before an update would proceed.

I currently have a linux setup and I have the liceanse for Windows 7, but I don't want to have to downoad two 4 GB isos.

Comment: @Misha - You must have an existing Windows installation already installed unless you are using a System Builder OEM Windows 8 installer.

Comment: @Ramhound is this a question of the media or the liceanse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**.

Selecting `Nothing` when the upgrade assistant asks you to choose what to keep will let you do a clean install.

The upgrade assistant will then let you download the ISO file which contains the Windows 8 installer. You can burn the ISO file to a DVD or create a bootable USB flash drive to install Windows 8.

**Also, you can use the Windows Upgrade Assistant to buy an upgrade license on one PC and use the product key on a different PC.**

Comment: He still needs an eligible Windows installation installed the installer will check.  Only the system builder oem doesn't require a previous installation.

Comment: Updated answer.